# Capturing a variable number of arguments via an ellipsis in a nested macro; Missing pattern variable error

Tags: macros, racket

Consider a scenario of two macros: the `outer-macro` defines a general structure of some entity, and the `inner-macro` expands in the scope of the outer macro. My intent is captured in the following code, where the expected output is a print statement. This example throws the following error for the pattern of the inner macro: `(_ value ...)`.

```
syntax: no pattern variables before ellipsis in template in: ...
```

I intend to use `value ...` in the same way as the `body ...` pattern of the outer macro. In fact, a list of the 'values' is exactly what I need (not necessarily a very flexible 'ellipsis pattern'). Sadly it does not work this way. How can I capture a variable amount of arguments in the inner macro?

```
#lang racket

(require
  racket/stxparam
  (for-syntax syntax/parse))

(define-syntax-parameter inner-macro
  (lambda (stx)
    (raise-syntax-error 'inner-macro "generic error message" stx)))

(define-syntax (outter-macro stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
    [(_ body:expr ...+)
     #'(syntax-parameterize
        ([inner-macro
          (lambda (stx)
            (syntax-case stx ()
              [(_ value ...)
               (printf "values are: ~a~n" (list value ...))]))])
        body ...)]))

(outter-macro
 (inner-macro 'a 'b 'c))

; expected result
; > "values are: (a b c)"
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To “escape” ellipses in syntax templates, you can use the syntax `(... <form>)`, where `<form>` is a syntax template where `...` sequences are treated literally. Therefore, you can wrap a piece of syntax to include literal ellipses:

```
> #'(... (syntax-rules ()
           [(x ...) (list x ...)]))
#<syntax:4:9 (syntax-rules () ((x ...) (li...>
```

You can use this to surround your inner macro definition to escape the inner ellipses:

```
(define-syntax (outer-macro stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
    [(_ body:expr ...+)
     #'(syntax-parameterize
        ([inner-macro
          (lambda (stx)
            (... (syntax-case stx ()
                   [(_ value ...)
                    (printf "values are: ~a~n" (list value ...))])))])
        body ...)]))
```

However, this is actually not quite right, because your `syntax-case` body is wrong—it does not return a syntax object. You are just missing a `#'` before the `(printf ...)` (or you could use `syntax-rules`), so the correct implementation should be the following:

```
(define-syntax (outer-macro stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
    [(_ body:expr ...+)
     #'(syntax-parameterize
        ([inner-macro
          (lambda (stx)
            (... (syntax-case stx ()
                   [(_ value ...)
                    #'(printf "values are: ~a~n" (list value ...))])))])
        body ...)]))
```

This should work as intended.

Comment: Can confirm this works, but was unable to find it in documentation.  Anybody know where this usage of `...` exists in the docs?

Answer (score 10):

Alexis King's answer is good. However another way to do it, which I find simpler to think about, is to use a `#:with` pattern (or a `with-syntax`), to define something like `ooo` as a literal ellipsis.

You can create a literal ellipsis with `quote-syntax`, so the `#:with` clause looks like `#:with ooo (quote-syntax ...)`. Then you use `ooo` whenever you want to generate an ellipsis in the output of the macro.

```
(define-syntax (outer-macro stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
    [(_ body:expr ...+)
     #:with ooo (quote-syntax ...)
     #'(syntax-parameterize
        ([inner-macro
          (lambda (stx)
            (syntax-case stx ()
              [(_ value ooo)
               #'(printf "values are: ~a~n" (list value ooo))]))])
    body ...)]))
```

Comment: That is indeed a nice way to do it, although I am still undecided on the *best* way. Thanks!

Comment: This question has 3 different styles of doing this: [defining macro-generated macros that take in a variable number of arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53863620/defining-macro-generated-macros-that-take-in-variable-number-of-arguments)