# defining macro-generated macros that take in variable number of arguments

Tags: racket

I am trying to write a macro-generating macro, where the macro it generates takes a variable number of arguments.

I am wondering if there is a way to make the following code work:

```
(define-syntax-rule (greet name)
  (define-syntax-rule (name args ...)
    (printf "hello ~a~n" (list args ...))))
```

Right now it says "no `pattern variables` before `ellipsis` in `template` in: `...`"

If I take the inner `define-syntax-rule` by itself it works fine, so why doesn't it work when it's being generated by another macro?

Comment: One important element to this question is that you're defining a macro-generating macro, where the generated macro takes a variable number of arguments. If you just write the inner `define-syntax-rule` directly, there's no problem. It's only putting that inside another outer `define-syntax-rule` that causes the problem.

Comment: This question may be related: [Capturing a variable number of arguments via an ellipsis in a nested macro; Missing pattern variable error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38275779/capturing-a-variable-number-of-arguments-via-an-ellipsis-in-a-nested-macro-miss)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are at least 3 "Styles" of doing this.

#### 1: Ellipsis-quoting each ellipsis separately

Soegaard [already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53863620/defining-macro-generated-macros-that-take-in-variable-number-of-arguments/53866670#53866670) that you can replace every `...` in the body with `(... ...)`, so that it gets interpreted as a literal ellipsis belonging to the inner macro instead of as a "meta" ellipsis belonging to the outer macro:

```
(define-syntax-rule (greet name)
  (define-syntax-rule (name args (... ...))
    (printf "hello ~a~n" (list args (... ...)))))
```

Advantages: Flexible, you can mix literal `(... ...)` and meta `...` ellipses freely within the body

Disadvantages: Looks confusing if you haven't seen `(... ...)` before

#### 2: Ellipsis-quoting the whole inner macro definition

However, putting `(... <something>)` around something is not limited to just `...`. If you put a whole template there, any `...`s within that template will also be "quoted", treated as literal instead of meta, in the same way:

```
(define-syntax-rule (greet name)
  (...
   (define-syntax-rule (name args ...)
     (printf "hello ~a~n" (list args ...)))))
```

Advantages: If you have even greater nesting depths you wouldn't need `((... ...) (... ...))` as you would with option 1, you would just need `(... <something-containing (... <something>)>)`

Disadvantages: Rigid, if you put `(... <something>)` around something you can't ever use a meta ellipsis inside that something. You can't mix literal and meta ellipses freely like you could with style 1 or 3.

#### 3: Creating a pattern-variable to represent a literal ellipsis

Here's another way, which I find less confusing, but it requires using `define-simple-macro` instead of `define-syntax-rule`, so that you can bind new pattern variables using `#:with`.

```
(require syntax/parse/define)

(define-simple-macro (<name> <arguments>)
  #:with <pattern-variable> <expression>
  <body-expression>)
```

You can use with `#:with` to bind an `ooo` pattern variable to a literal ellipsis: `#:with ooo (quote-syntax ...)`

```
(require syntax/parse/define)

(define-simple-macro (greet name)
  #:with ooo (quote-syntax ...)
  (define-syntax-rule (name args ooo)
    (printf "hello ~a~n" (list args ooo))))
```

Advantages: Flexible, you can mix literal `ooo` and meta `...` ellipses freely within the body. To me, it looks less confusing than `(... ...)` or `((... ...) (... ...))`.

Disadvantages: For deeper nesting, you might need multiple `#:with`-definitions, one on each meta-level.

Answer (score 5):

The `...` belongs to the outer `define-syntax-rule`. In order
to produce an ellipsis in the output you need to quote it with `(... ...)`.

```
(define-syntax-rule (greet name)
  (define-syntax-rule (name args (... ...))
    (printf "hello ~a~n" (list args (... ...)))))
```

For fun: If you ever need to write a macro that produces a macro that produces a macro, you will need `((... ...) (... ...))` to produce an ellipsis.